# Is compression no longer supported in Akka 2.0?

Tags: scala, zlib, akka

I was using zlib compression on messages in Akka 1.3. I'm now migrating to Akka 2.0 RC2, and it seems that message compression is no longer mentioned in the Akka documentation (for Akka 2.0 RC2).

Does this mean message compression is no longer supported in Akka 2, or is compression happening behind the scenes but compression options are no longer configurable?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Searching the Akka-User mailinglist for compression will reveal the reason it doesn't exist in 2.0 => it was completely messing up throughput. Here's the relevant posts: http://groups.google.com/group/akka-user/search?hl=en_US&q=compression&start=0&scoring=d&hl=en_US&

Comment: However... You can write your own Serializer that also does compression. (For 2.0 that is)

Answer (score 2):

Messages are binary blobs. You can put whatever you want into them. If there is an advantage to compressing your messages, just do it before sending them. There is no performance advantage to having Akka do the job for you.

Comment: Let Akka do the Serialization, then it's done at the proper place, and that does not leak into your code.